# How do I find a view inside a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to add a fragment, then find a view inside said fragment, and add a view into it. However I keep getting a NullPointerException on this statement

```
  FrameLayout container2 = (FrameLayout) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
```

Here is my code. Can someone tell me how to fix this please? thanks

```
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentNavigationDrawer();
    ViewGroup decor = (ViewGroup) getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
    View child = decor.getChildAt(0);
    decor.removeView(child);
    fragmentTransaction.add(decor.getId(), fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
    FrameLayout container2 = (FrameLayout) fragment.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    container2.addView(child);
```

Comment: Why do you do Fragment.getActivity from the Activity that the Fragment is contained within?

Comment: Where is this piece of code reside? In the activity or in a fragment?

Comment: Use the fragment's `getView` method and call `findViewById` on the returned view.

Comment: 1. not sure, 2. a fragment

Answer (score 2):

Just use a getter. Set a tag on your fragment so you can access it later, then either call `getView()` on your fragment to return its root view, or use a getter to access a specific `View`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //In onCreate
    if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentNavigationDrawer.TAG) == null) {
        getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(android.R.id.content, new FragmentNavigationDrawer(), FragmentNavigationDrawer.TAG)
            .commit();
    }

    //Later, when you want to add said View:
    FragmentNavigationDrawer frag = 
        (FragmentNavigationDrawer) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FragmentNavigationDrawer.TAG)

    //Return the root view:
    View fragRootView = frag.getView();

    //Return a specific view:
    frag.getUpdatableViewGroup().addView(newViewToAdd):

}
```

For your Fragment:

```
public class FragmentNavigationDrawer extends Fragment {

    public static final String TAG = FragmentNavigationDrawer.class.getSimpleName();

    FrameLayout updatableViewGroup;

    //Can do this inside onCreateView() whilst inflating your Fragment's Views
   //That's up to you.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated (View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        updateableViewGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.updateable_view_group);

    }

    public FrameLayout getUpdatableViewGroup() {
        return updateableViewGroup;
    }
```

Be conscious of the `Activity` and `Fragment` life cycles however, and be careful not to attempt to access the Fragment's Views until they have finished inflating - `onStart()` of your `Activity` and later should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the javadoc for [FragmentTransaction.commit()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#commit%28%29).  It says it will *schedule* a change to the fragment back stack.  It doesn't happen immediately.  It looks like you're expecting the fragment and its views to be instantly available.

Also, I'm really confused why you're reaching in a decor view to make changes.  Usually you call out a view by id in the host activity's layout and make changes inside it.

Comment: I think OP needs to use `FragmentTransaction.replace`